# Ubuntu 18 LTS AD configuration User

Tags: 18.04, active-directory

I have Ubuntu client joining AD.

Ad users are connecting and creating home directory well.

I want to add to all ad user:

- desktop shortcuts
- sidebar shortcuts
- Program installed by Wine and and link on desktop and sidebar

How can I do that properly?

Answer (score 0):

You should trying config in /etc/skel

> mkdir -p /etc/skel/Desktop && cd /etc/skel/Desktop/
>
> vi shortcut.Desktop
>
> ```
> [Desktop Entry]
> Version=1.0
> Name=ShortCut
> GenericName=ShortCut
> Comment=Visit ShortCut
> Exec=firefox http://www.google.com
> Terminal=false
> X-MultipleArgs=false
> Type=Application
> Icon=firefox
> Categories=Internet
> etc.....
> ```
>
> chmod +x shortcut.Desktop

Comment: 0


and for :

Program installed by Wine (root) and and link on desktop and sidebar of the user ?